# Highchart: Plotting datetime chart issue when passing series map from java

Tags: javascript, java, datetime, highcharts

I am trying to plot a datetime chart in highchart. I am passing series map from java HashMap and accessing it in js as:

```
var chartRoot = '#{value}'.evalJSON(true);
```

And feeding the map in series as:

```
series : [{color:'#057E7E',
                                data : chartRoot.series[0].y1axis,
                                name:'#{empty y1axistitle ? '' : y1axistitle}',
                                type: 'line',
                                tooltip: {
                                    valuePrefix: ''
                               }
                              },{
                                color:'#FF8230',
                                data : chartRoot.series[0].y2axis,
                                name:'#{empty y2axistitle ? '' : y2axistitle}',
                                type: 'line',
                                tooltip: {
                                    valuePrefix: '$'
                               },
                                yAxis: 1
                                  }]
```

where y1axis and y2axis are hashMap with data for 2 y axis.

I am not able to plot graph like this. I even changed the type of hash map to  but it did not work.
Please help me I am new to highchart.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show what do you have in `chartRoot.series[0].y1axis` ? For example `console.log(chartRoot.series[0].y1axis)`.

Comment: Object { 1325376000000=1.09, 1330560000000=1.66, 1333238400000=0.55, more...}
Basically, its a map of type long,Float where long represents time in milliseconds
In my test highchart file I am using series as:
data: [
             [1325376000000, 5   ],
    [1328054400000, 10   ],
    [1330560000000, 25   ],
    [1333238400000, 35   ],
    [1335830400000, 68   ]
         ]
which is working perfectily. I don't know what's wrong with my code above.

Comment: what I suspect is the format of the data is the issue. Is there any way where I can change Object { 1325376000000=1.09} in chartRoot.series[0].y1axis to [ [1325376000000, 5 ]] in javascript.
Refer the above comment as well

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with your data. Currently you have object:

```
{ 
  1325376000000: 1.09, 
  1330560000000: 1.66, 
  1333238400000: 0.55, 
  more...
}
```

While there should be:

```
[ 
  [1325376000000, 1.09], 
  [1330560000000, 1.66], 
  [1333238400000, 0.55], 
  more...
]
```

You can re-format this in JS:

```
var myData = [];

for (var time in chartRoot.series[0].y1axis) {
  myData.push([time, chartRoot.series[0].y1axis[time]]);
}
```

And now use `myData` in `series.data` option.